# Benefit of Drazin inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

What benefits gives [Drazin Inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drazin_inverse)? 
Physically what it corresponds to?

Thanks much

Comment: Could those voting to close please explain to the OP *why* you consider this "not a real question"? It even ends with a question mark!

Answer (score 2):

When you use Krylov Methods to solve a system of linear equations, the Drazin inverse gives the unique Krylov solution provided the equation is consistent. Find more [here](http://meyer.math.ncsu.edu/Meyer/PS_Files/Krylov.pdf).